# How can I Bang Bang after $?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

In writing a function designed to compare columns from two dataframes, I'm hoping to figure out how I might refer to a variable specified as an argument to the function after a $.

Consider this data:

```
data1<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),Amt=c(5,10,15,20,25,30),Term=c(2,3,2,3,2,3))
data2<-data.frame(Id=c(1,2,3),TERM=c(1,2,3))
```

And this failed function:

```
two_df_function<-function(df,df2,id,id2,term,term2){

  id<-rlang::ensym(id)
  id2<-rlang::ensym(id2)
  term<-rlang::ensym(term)
  term2<-rlang::ensym(term2)

  data_out<-df%>%
    group_by(!!term)%>%
    mutate(Early=ifelse(!!id %in% df2$!!id2[df2$!!term2 < !!term],1,0))
}
```

I receive "Error: unexpected '!' in:"

To get my desired result, I plugged in the dataframe and column names manually:

```
data_out<-data1%>%
  group_by(Term)%>%
  mutate(Early=ifelse(ID %in% data2$Id[data2$TERM < Term],1,0))
```

which yields:

[image]

Because I would like a function, I tried resolving by simply taking out the unexpected symbols.

The following will run, but gives incorrect results:

```
two_df_function<-function(df,df2,id,id2,term,term2){

  id<-rlang::ensym(id)
  id2<-rlang::ensym(id2)
  term<-rlang::ensym(term)
  term2<-rlang::ensym(term2)


  data_out<-df%>%
    group_by(!!term)%>%
    mutate(Early=ifelse(!!id %in% df2$id2[df2$term2 < !!term],1,0))

  return(data_out)

}
```

Incorrect results after using this:

[image]

Is there a way to bang bang after $ and get my function to succeed?  Alternatively, is there a better way to write this function so as to avoid the problem?

Comment: Some great answers below from @www @Ronak Shah and @Sirius.  Is there a more general answer regarding the failure of `df2$!!term2`? Or a way to get that to function without having to rework the approach to the problem?

Answer (score 5):

We can bang bang without $ using `dplyr` as follows. By the way, I think `group_by` is not needed in this case if you join the two data frames.

```
library(dplyr)

two_df <- function(df, df2, id, id2, term, term2){
  
  df_out <- df %>%
    left_join(df2, by = setNames(id2, id)) %>%
    mutate(Early = as.integer(.data[[term]] > .data[[term2]])) %>%
    select(-all_of(term2))
  
  return(df_out)
  
}

two_df(data1, data2, id = "ID", id2 = "Id", term = "Term", term2 = "TERM")
#   ID Amt Term Early
# 1  1   5    2     1
# 2  1  10    3     1
# 3  2  15    2     0
# 4  2  20    3     1
# 5  3  25    2     0
# 6  3  30    3     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R one-liner using `match` :

```
two_df_function<-function(df,df2,id,id2,term,term2) {
  transform(df, 
     Early = as.integer(df[[term]] > df2[[term2]][match(df[[id]],df2[[id2]])]))
}

two_df_function(data1, data2, 'ID', 'Id', 'Term', 'TERM')

#  ID Amt Term Early
#1  1   5    2     1
#2  1  10    3     1
#3  2  15    2     0
#4  2  20    3     1
#5  3  25    2     0
#6  3  30    3     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it all have to be in tidyverse? If not:

```
two_df_function<-function(df,df2,id,id2,term,term2){

    id <- as.character(substitute(id))
    id2 <- as.character(substitute(id2))
    term <- rlang::ensym(term)
    term2 <- as.character(substitute(term2))

    data1 %>%
        group_by( !!term ) %>%
        mutate(Early= ifelse( id %in% data2[,id2][ data2[,term2] < !!term], 1, 0 ) )

}
```

Comment: I tested your function and all the values in the `Early` column are zero. It seems like something is wrong.

Comment: You are correct , I missed that! There seems to be another correct and clean looking answer here though. If you still want to use the no-quote functoin arguments, just do as.character substitute on the 4 names and use the rest of the function body from www's answer

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a bang bang after $, the column can be referenced using brackets and `names()`.

**As a functioning alternative to `df2$!!id2`, it is possible to use `df2[,names(df2) %in% c(id2)]`**
At least when `rlang::ensym(id2)` precedes it in the writing of a function.

In using the example from the question above, the following function works as intended:

```
  two_df_functionb<-function(df,df2,id,id2,term,term2){

  id<-rlang::ensym(id)
  id2<-rlang::ensym(id2)
  term<-rlang::ensym(term)
  term2<-rlang::ensym(term2)

  data_out<-df%>%
    group_by(!!term)%>%
    mutate(Early=ifelse(!!id %in% df2[,names(df2) %in% c(id2)][df2[,names(df2) %in% 
c(term2)]<!!term],1,0))

  return(data_out)
}
```